# System() command not working when enabling app sandboxing

Tags: xcode, cocoa, system, entitlements, sandbox

Apple now require all future apps to be sandboxed and so I followed the instructions to sandbox an app. The build succeeded but then my `system(rm -rf ~/.Trash/*)` command stopped working. Nothing happened. What I find confusing here is why this system command does not work with App Sandboxing/Entitlements on. Here is are my entitlement settings:

Entitlements: Checked

App Sandboxing: Checked

And here is my current code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[self emptyTrash];
}

- (void)emptyTrash {
system(rm -rf ~/.Trash/*);
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you sure emptying the user's trash is something you should be doing anyway?  I, for one, am glad sandboxing stops you from doing it!

Comment: I'm not 100% certain (so I'm just saying it in a comment), but if I recall correctly, when in Sandbox mode, `~` does not resolve to `/Users/username/`, but to some folder in `~/Library/Application Data` or something like that... Check the docs on Sandboxing again.

Comment: Why do you need to use system() to delete a directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/DesigningYourSandbox/DesigningYourSandbox.html).

> Mac OS X path-finding APIs, above the POSIX layer, return paths
>   relative to the container instead of relative to the user’s home
>   directory. If your app, before you sandbox it, accesses locations in
>   the user’s actual home directory (~) and you are using Cocoa or Core
>   Foundation APIs, then, after you enable sandboxing, your path-finding
>   code automatically uses your app’s container instead.

you can use

```
struct passwd *getpwuid(uid_t uid);
struct passwd {
char    *pw_name;       /* user name */
char    *pw_passwd;     /* encrypted password */
uid_t   pw_uid;         /* user uid */
gid_t   pw_gid;         /* user gid */
__darwin_time_t pw_change;      /* password change time */
char    *pw_class;      /* user access class */
char    *pw_gecos;      /* Honeywell login info */
char    *pw_dir;        /* home directory */
char    *pw_shell;      /* default shell */
__darwin_time_t pw_expire;      /* account expiration */
}

 #include <pwd.h>
 #include <sys/types.h>
 char *HomeDirectory = getpwuid(getuid())->pw_dir;
 NSLog(@"%s", HomeDirectory);
 system([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"rm -rf %s/.Trash/",HomeDirectory] UTF8String]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works a treat!