# System command for checking driver details not working after enabling app sandbox

Tags: macos, sandbox

In my cocoa application, i am checking whether the drivers are installed in system.

Here is the code for checking driver installation

```
if (0 == system("lpstat -p MyDriver"))
{
   //Code inside if
}
```

it works fine and showing driver details without enabling sandbox. But after enabling sandbox,
it shows `lpstat: Invalid destination name in list "MyDriver"` error.

And i found some reference [System() command not working when enabling app sandboxing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291164/system-command-not-working-when-enabling-app-sandboxing). In this reference, they are using password  privillages to delete directory.  but my scenario here is different, i'm just checking whether the drivers were installed or not.

Is there any solution to to check driver installation details if sandbox enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above given system commands works fine, after enabling allow printing option in Entitlements.

[image]